# How to use VBA in Excel for Google Search?

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome, search, google-search

I'm trying to implement a Google Search method using VBA in Excel.

I would like to type a certain word/words in the pop-up window, whereupon it Google searches the word/words + a predetermined phrase.

For example, if I type "John Doe", I would like the Google search to be "John Doe License and Registration", without having to type "License and Registration" every time I type a name.

How do I add the "License and Registration" in my code?

```vb
Private Sub CommandButtonSearch_Click()
    Dim query As String
    Dim search_string As String
    Dim googleChromePath As String
    
    query = InputBox("Enter your keyword", "Google Search")
    search_string = Replace(query, " ", "+")
    
    googleChromePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    
    Shell (googleChromePath & " -url http://google.com/search?q=" & search_string)

End Sub
```

How it looks:
[image]

How I would like it to look:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Private Const LicenseRegistration As String = "+License+and+Registration"
Private Sub CommandButtonSearch_Click()
    Dim query As String
    Dim search_string As String
    Dim googleChromePath As String
    
    query = InputBox("Enter your keyword", "Google Search")
    search_string = Replace(query, " ", "+") & LicenseRegistration
    
    googleChromePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    
    Shell (googleChromePath & " -url http://google.com/search?q=" & search_string)

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for. Sorry to bother you with a second question, but do you happen to know a way to store all Google searches from Excel in either the same Excel file but in another sheet, or a completely different file? Thanks again!

Comment: sorry to burden you again, but did you get a chance to look at the second question I had a problem with?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps.

```
Sub Gethits()
    Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
    Dim start_time As Date
    Dim end_time As Date
    Dim var As String
    Dim var1 As Object

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    Dim cookie As String
    Dim result_cookie As String

    start_time = Time
    Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1)
        Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
        XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
        XMLHTTP.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
        Set objResultDiv = html.getElementById("rso")
        Set var1 = html.getElementById("result-stats")
        Cells(i, 2).Value = var1.innerText

        DoEvents
    Next

    end_time = Time
    Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

    Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
    MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]